# Angular Js dropdown Selected Value undefined inside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to select a dropdown value in angularJs and save it in a service so that i can use it on another view to display the user his selected value and full dropdown.But when i try to log the selected value inside controller.I am getting value of undefined.Please help me how to proceed.

```
<td>
  <select name="systems" class="pulldown1" id="systems" ng-model="system.selectedOption" ng-controller="EurexController" required ng-options="option.name for option in system.availableOptions track by option.id" ng-init="system.selectedOption=system.availableOptions[0]" ng-change="changed()"> </select>
</td>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.system = {
  availableOptions: [{
    id: 'Domestic 1',
    name: 'Domestic 1'
  }, {
    id: 'Domestic 2',
    name: 'Domestic 2'
  }, {
    id: 'Global',
    name: 'Global'
  }, {
    id: 'Far East',
    name: 'Far East'
  }],
  // selectedOption: {id: 'Domestic 1', name: 'Domestic 1'} //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
};
```

I also tried using selectedoption mentioned in AngularJS website.But still couldnt do it.

```
console.log($scope.system.selectedOption);
console.log(systems);
```

Comment: This is a Valid Question and I got my answer . Could someone say why is this downvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to put your `ng-controller` attribute on a container element instead of directly on the something like a `<select>` element. This allows you to use the controller throughout your view instead of limiting it to the `<select>` element. Your `console.log(systems);` is undefined because `systems` does not exist in the controller context. Avoid using `ng-init` unless you really need it as described in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Here is a working example using a modified version of the code you provided:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.system = {
      availableOptions: [{
        id: 'Domestic 1',
        name: 'Domestic 1'
      }, {
        id: 'Domestic 2',
        name: 'Domestic 2'
      }, {
        id: 'Global',
        name: 'Global'
      }, {
        id: 'Far East',
        name: 'Far East'
      }]
    };

    $scope.system.selectedOption = {};
    // uncomment the following line if you want to set a default selection
    //$scope.system.selectedOption = $scope.system.availableOptions[0];

    $scope.optionChanged = function() {
      myService.optionValue = $scope.system.selectedOption;
      console.log($scope.system.selectedOption);
    }
  })
  .controller('ctrl2', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.myService = myService;
  })
  .service('myService', function() {
    var _optionValue = {};
    return {
      get optionValue() {
          return _optionValue;
        },
        set optionValue(value) {
          _optionValue = value || {};
        }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h2>ctrl</h2>
    <div>
      <select ng-model="system.selectedOption" ng-options="option as option.name for option in system.availableOptions" ng-change="optionChanged()">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      Selected option: {{ system.selectedOption | json }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl2'>
    <h2>ctrl2</h2>
    <div>
      {{ myService.optionValue }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why i used ng-init  was i always want the first item to be displayed on the dropdown . can you guide me on how should i write down a angular service/factory so that i can set the selected value on scope. The main idea of having the value in service/factory is because . I am taking the user to next page after the system is selected. There i need to show him again the system he is selected. kind of a redispaly page.If the user wants to see what he has selected.

Comment: It's a bit out of the scope of your original question, but I have updated the answer to show how you could use a service with a getter/setter to share the selected option between two controllers.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I upvoted it . But its saying me they will hide it coz i have less reputation

Comment: Hey, Did You forgot to add the service code/guide. I am not able to see it

Comment: Hey Lex. I am setting the deafult value inside the controller . whenever i do a onchange event the same controller will be getting called and wont the default value will be coming again inside the controller ?